# cannot read property 'fromJS' of undefined in external viewmodel.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I keep getting the error : **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromJS' of undefined**
The idea is to have 2 pages, where is the the ui representation and the other one is het viewmodel.
I have 2 pages:

Index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bin/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bin/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bin/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bin/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" />

<script src="bin/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bin/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="bin/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="bin/knockout.mapping-latest.js" type="text/html"></script>

<script src="IndexViewModel.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        var indexVM = new IndexViewModel.ViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(indexVM);
    });
</script>


<table>
    <thead><tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
    </tr></thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Users">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: UserName"/></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and IndexViewModel.js :

```
var IndexViewModel = (function (IndexViewModel) {
IndexViewModel.ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.Users = ko.observableArray();
    $.ajax({
        url : 'GetUsers.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){ //json string of the student records returned from the server
        self.Users = ko.mapping.fromJS(result.data, {}, self.Users);
        }
    });
}
    return IndexViewModel;
}(IndexViewModel || {}));
```

What am I doing wrong / missing?

Thanks

Comment: Can you check the network tab in the browser developer tools and make sure knockout.mapping-latest.js is downloaded?

Comment: Yes, it does get loaded.
But knockout.mapping-latest.js should be referrenced in the index.html, not in the indexviewmodel.js, right?

Remote Address:[::1]:80
Request URL:http://localhost/bin/knockout.mapping-latest.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified
Request Headersview source

Comment: Can you take a look at the content. It should have ko.mapping in it like this:   `factory(ko, ko.mapping = {});` https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/blob/master/knockout.mapping.js

Comment: It didn't. I copied the complete contents of the github link you provided into a new file knockout.mappings.js and referenced the file in the index.html

Same error though.

Comment: It's definitely something to do with the knockout mapping file not loading correctly. Here's your code working in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7mnoodn8/).

Comment: Thank you very much. Solved the issue.
Problem was <script src="bin/knockout.mapping-latest.js" type="text/html"></script>

changed to :

<script src="bin/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the issue. Problem was

```
<script src="bin/knockout.mapping-latest.js" type="text/html"></script>
```

changed to :

```
<script src="bin/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
```

Taking off : **type="text/html"**